# PostgreSQL function to create and populate data doesn't seem to do anything after it runs

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

Here is what I am trying to do:

I have a huge table with millions of rows. I’ll provide a simpler example:

```
Table Living_Things:

Type        |Category       |Name       
Bird        |Parrot         |Sophie
Animal      |Dog            |Momo
Animal      |Cat            |Daisy
Animal      |Dog            |Tom
Bird        |Parrot         |Fire
Animal      |Cat            |Moon
```

What I wish to achieve here is as follows:

1. Create a function create_and_insert() which:
2. Gets category as an input
3. Create a variable and store concatenated result of “Category_”, , “Table” into it. Also, replace most special characters that may possibly appear in the category input to underscore. So Dog will become Category_Dog_Table; “Tall Tree” will become Category_Tall_Tree_Table.
4. Create a table with the name created in step (b) and insert everything from that category into this new table
5. Create indexes on the table. Note the table has millions of rows, thus we do not want indexing to happen during each insert. So do this at the end.

Then we call this using the following:

1. Create an unnamed block that does the following:
2. Selects distinct categories from table Living_Things
3. Calls function create_and_insert() for each of these distinct categories

So at the end of this process, We will have the following new tables:

```
1.  Category_Parrot_Table:
Bird        |Parrot     |Sophie
Bird        |Parrot     |Fire

2.  Category_Dog_Table:
Animal      |Dog            |Momo
Animal      |Dog            |Tom

3.  Category_Cat_Table:
Animal      |Cat            |Daisy
Animal      |Cat            |Moon
```

Following is my attempt to achieve this, but it doesn’t seem to do anything:

1. Create function:

```
    DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS public.create_and_insert (text) ;
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public. create_and_insert(
       cat_name text)
        RETURNS void
        LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    AS $BODY$
    DECLARE
        cat_table_name text;
    BEGIN
        SELECT CONCAT('Category_', replace(replace(trim(BOTH ' "' FROM regexp_split_to_table(trim(BOTH '[]' FROM cat_name), E'\,')),':','_'),'-','_'), '_Table')
        INTO cat_table_name;
    
        -- EXECUTE format(
        PERFORM format(
            'CREATE TABLE %I AS
            SELECT * FROM Living_Things
            WHERE Category = %I', cat_table_name, cat_name
    
        );
        EXECUTE 'CREATE INDEX ' || cat_table_name ||'_idx ON ' || cat_table_name ||' USING spgist ( name )';
    END;
    $BODY$;
    
    completed in 12 ms
```

2. Call the function with each category:

```
    DO
    $$
    DECLARE cat_name text;
    BEGIN
    FOR cat_name IN (SELECT DISTINCT Category FROM Living_Things) LOOP
        PERFORM public. create_and_insert(cat_name);
        -- EXECUTE public. create_and_insert( cat_name );
        END LOOP;
    END;
    $$;
    completed in 45 s 633 ms
```

But None of the expected tables are created. What am I doing wrong?

Note 1: I know that this is not the best normalization, etc. etc. Please remember that this is a hypothetical example I created just for explaining the situation, and not the real case. In the real case, I am dealing with millions of rows of cartography information. And that's also the reason for using spgist for indexing.

Note 2: I am using PostgreSQL 13.3 (hosted on AWS RDS)

Note 3: The following works and creates the table, but I am looking to optimize it by inserting data when it is created. Currently, we go over the Living_Things table sequentially and insert it into one of the 100s of tables created using the below step one by one:

```
    DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS public.create_cat_table(text) ;
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.create_cat_table(
        cat_table text)
        RETURNS void
        LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    AS $BODY$
    BEGIN
        EXECUTE format(
            'CREATE TABLE %I (
                Type varchar,
                Category varchar,
                Name varchar,
                PRIMARY KEY ( Name )
             )', cat_table);
        EXECUTE 'CREATE INDEX ' || cat_table ||'_idx ON ' || cat_table ||' USING spgist ( name )';
    END;
    $BODY$;
```

Comment: You need to change the title of your question as you have a function that does create a table. I would revamp the question to ask how to move data into the new table.

Comment: The new code which has

PERFORM format(
            'CREATE TABLE %I AS
            SELECT * FROM Living_Things
            WHERE Category = %I', cat_table_name, cat_name

does not even create a table.

Comment: It won't as that will just create a formatted `CREATE TABLE ...` string. It does not actually create the table. Your `EXECUTE format(...`  does do that as it executes the formatted string to create a table.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver - Tried that and got another error. Details are in reply to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69172265/7524805

Comment: You need to update your question with the revised function and the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was playing around with PERFORM and EXECUTE this whole time, around 3 days prior to my posting of this question.

I kept getting different errors when I changed the query to use EXECUTE and when I changed it to use PERFORM. Yes, EXECUTE worked, but only when I fixed the real problem.

The real problem:
If you see my original code posted in the question, I am using "WHERE Category = %I" in create_and_insert(). The **%I is the issue** as it was trying to insert the value of cat_name there as an identifier. But the usage, in this case, was as literal. So **changing %I to %L was the missing block in here**.

Note: "**RAISE NOTICE**" command is a very useful utility to debug your functions in PostgreSQL. It helped me to be sure that the "SELECT INTO" is working by printing the value while debugging, and was able to help me pinpoint which line of code it had issues in

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS public.create_and_insert(text) ;
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.create_and_insert(
    cat_name text)
    RETURNS void
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $BODY$
DECLARE
    cat_table_name text;
BEGIN
    --RAISE NOTICE 'Before select concat - 01';
    SELECT CONCAT('Category_', replace(replace(trim(BOTH ' "' FROM regexp_split_to_table(trim(BOTH '[]' FROM cat_name), E'\,')),':','_'),'-','_'), '_Table')
    INTO cat_table_name;

    --RAISE NOTICE 'After SELECT CONCAT - 02 - %, %', cat_name, cat_table_name;
    EXECUTE format('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS %I', cat_table_name);
    EXECUTE format(
        'CREATE TABLE %I AS
        SELECT * FROM Living_Things
        WHERE nsubtype = %L', cat_table_name, cat_name
    );

    --RAISE NOTICE 'after CREATE TABLE - 03';
    EXECUTE 'CREATE INDEX ' || cat_table_name ||'_idx ON ' || cat_table_name ||' USING spgist (name)';
    --RAISE NOTICE 'after CREATE INDEX - 04';
    EXECUTE 'ALTER TABLE ' || cat_table_name || ' ADD CONSTRAINT ' || cat_table_name || '_pk PRIMARY KEY (some_column);';
    --RAISE NOTICE 'after ADD PRIMARY KEY - 05';
END;
$BODY$;
```

Call the function using this:

```
DO
$$
DECLARE cat_name text;
BEGIN
FOR cat_name IN (SELECT DISTINCT nsubtype as cat_name FROM Living_Things) LOOP
    --RAISE NOTICE 'Calling create_and_insert( % )', cat_name;
    EXECUTE public.create_and_insert( cat_name );
    END LOOP;
END;
$$;
```

Answer (score 0):

`PERFORM format()` is nonsense. It prepare query (by function format) and throws it. You need to use `EXECUTE` statement.

Comment: Did that change, and I got this:
=====
[42601] ERROR: syntax error at or near "Living_Things"
Where: PL/pgSQL function create_and_insert(text) line 8 at EXECUTE
SQL statement "SELECT public. create_and_insert( cat_name )"
PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 5 at PERFORM
=====
Then I tried changing the PERFORM public. create_and_insert(cat_name); to use EXECUTE too and got this: 
=====
[42601] ERROR: syntax error at or near "Living_Things"
Where: PL/pgSQL function create_cat_table(text) line 8 at EXECUTE
PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 6 at EXECUTE
=====

Comment: @NikhilBhirud - you cannot to change EXECUTE and PERFORM, there is absolutely different usage. Any result of EXECUTE expression should be valid SQL statement. Please, try to read doc https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN first,